# Updating gpt.ini file for local startup policy

Tags: powershell, group-policy

I'm planning to uninstall & install a software agent through machine startup policy whenever and issue is reported.  The batch file for uninstall/install and script.ini file will be copied over and this part is successful.

If I increment the gpt.ini version value by 1 manually and reboot the PC, the startup policy run successfully.

I'm able to increment the version value by 1 using PowerShell script but I understand this is not sufficient. The `gPCMachineExtensionNames` value needs to be appended as well which I need help with.

Current PowerShell script to update gpt.ini version value by 1:

```
$gptIniFilePath = 'RemotePC path'
$encoding = 'UTF8'
$gptIniContent = Get-Content -Encoding $encoding -Path $gptIniFilePath
foreach ($s in $gptIniContent) {
    if($s.StartsWith("Version")) {
        $num = ($s -split "=")[1] 
        $ver = [Convert]::ToInt32($num)
        $newVer = $ver + 1
        Write-Host $newver
        (Get-Content $gptIniFilePath) | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "$ver","$newver" } |
            Set-Content -Encoding $encoding $gptIniFilePath -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you were to [edit] your post to include the code of your script as actual text (not a picture of text).

Comment: Done, code is an actual text now

Answer (score 0):

After all the *help* you received after providing your code as text, I have some info which may be of interest to you.

"Version=x. This entry is the version number of the GPO, where x is the placeholder for a number specified by a version-counter function. Typically, the version number is zero-based, and each time you modify the GPO, this counter is incremented by 1. However, this number is a decimal representation of an eight-digit hexadecimal number (a DWORD), which is the data type the group policy processes understand. The four least significant digits represent the Computer Settings version number, and the four most significant digits represent the User Settings version number. In other words, if you see Version=65539, the computer understands this as hexadecimal 0x00010003, which tells it that the Computer Settings version is 3, and the User Settings version is 1." [source is [https://www.serverbrain.org/administration-practice-2003/the-gptini-file.html]](https://www.serverbrain.org/administration-practice-2003/the-gptini-file.html)

This is actually the best explanation I've found as I'm engaged in this topic as well (my own use-case is adding/removing startup/logon/logoff/shutdown script **L**GPO policies programatically).

Next on the agenda is the GUID you asked for. After extensive testing (trial-and-error inclusive) I've found the following:

```
gPCMachineExtensionNames=[{42B5FAAE-6536-11D2-AE5A-0000F87571E3}{40B6664F-4972-11D1-A7CA-0000F87571E3}]
```

and, if you're interested,

```
gPCUserExtensionNames=[{42B5FAAE-6536-11D2-AE5A-0000F87571E3}{40B66650-4972-11D1-A7CA-0000F87571E3}]
```

These are the GUIDs for the startup/shutdown and logon/logoff policies on a non domain-joined computers, running Win10.

Unfortunately, as for the significance of the versioning, I'm at a loss. I mean, idk what happens when we get to 0xFFFFFFFF and there's a new change which requires incrementing the respective version. Personally, I've yet to find a corresponding value elsewhere (again, on a **local** machine) that would "verify" this version number.

I have also found the GUID list at [this link](https://www.infrastructureheroes.org/microsoft-infrastructure/microsoft-windows/guid-list-of-group-policy-client-extensions/), but I cannot verify it's **all** correct.

Hope I was of some help to you. Cheers.